# Axios returning 405 error on create (Laravel+Vue)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a form for "Books" and I'm sending a HTTP request through axios with post, it is returning 405 error

**My routes**

(web.php)

```
Route::redirect('/', 'login');
Auth::routes();
Route::resource('/books', 'books\BooksController')->middleware('auth');
```

I have seen that many people use the api routes but it has worked with web with me before (but with a less complex crud)

**My controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $book = new Book();
        $book->isbn = $request->isbn;
        $book->titulo_ori = $request->titulo_ori;
        $book->sinop = $request->sinop;
        $book->n_pag = $request->n_pag;
        $book->save();
        return $book;
    }
```

I am not using migrations so my model looks like this

**My model**

```
class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'sjl_libros';
    protected $fillable = ['isbn', 'titulo_ori' 'sinop', 'n_pag'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**My form**

```
<b-form @submit.prevent="add">
     <b-row>
         <b-col cols="4">
             <label for="isbn">ISBN</label>
                <b-form-input type="text" v-model="book.isbn" id="isbn" name="isbn"></b-form-input>
         </b-col>

          <b-col cols="4">
             <label for="titulo_ori">Original Title</label>
                <b-form-input type="text" v-model="book.titulo_ori" id="titulo_ori" name="titulo_ori"></b-form-input>
          </b-col>
 </b-row><br>

 <b-row>
     <b-col cols="12">
         <label for="sinop">Plot</label>
         <b-form-textarea v-model="book.sinop" size="lg" rows="8" id="sinop" name="sinop"></b-form-textarea>
     </b-col>
 </b-row><hr>

<b-row>
   <b-col cols="4">
      <label for="n_pag">Number of pages</label>
          <b-form-input v-model="book.n_pag" id="n_pag" name="n_pag"></b-form-input>
   </b-col>                                   
   </b-row><hr>

   <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse bd-highlight">
       <b-button variant="default" @click="add">Continue</b-button>
       <b-link class="btn btn-danger" href="/books">Cancel</b-link>
   </div>
</b-form>
```

**My axios script**

```
add() {
    const params = {
        isbn: this.book.isbn,
        titulo_ori: this.book.titulo_ori,
        sinop: this.book.titulo_esp,
        n_pag: this.book.n_pag,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
};


        axios.post('/books', params)
           .then(res => {
               alert('success');
               console.log(res.data);
                }). catch (e=> {
                    console.log(e);
                })
        },
```

The exact error I get in console is the following

```
Error: "Request failed with status code 405"
    createError http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:653
    settle http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:899
    handleLoad http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:166
```

What could I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I get 500 error now, I appended it like this
            `const params = {
                isbn: this.book.isbn,
                titulo_ori: this.book.titulo_ori,
                sinop: this.book.sinop,
                n_pag: this.book.n_pag,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            };`

Comment: Please run `php artisan route:list` and show us the result. I think your route uri shoud be `'/books'` instead `'/books/create'`

Comment: yeah, just edited my question, that's what made me get a 500 error now.

Comment: For a status 500 you must look at the Laravel logs `/yourproject/storage/logs/laravel.log` to know what it is. With `_token` field, I meant a field within the parameters just like the others you already have `const params = {   isbn: this.book.isbn,  titulo_ori: this.book.titulo_ori,   sinop: this.book.sinop,   n_pag: this.book.n_pag,   _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') };`, you should only add it to the headers if you had not done it before with something like `window.axios.defaults.headers.common = { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers) like the one you have:

```
Route::resource('books', 'books\BooksController');
```

will result for the post method in something like this:

```
Verb    URI        Action   Route Name
POST    /books     store    books.store
```

So for your axios `url`, you must use `'/books'` (the route `URI`)

```
axios.post('/books', params)
```

---

Also you will need to add the [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-introduction) token in a `_token` field. You can append it to the `params` object

```
const params = { 
    isbn: this.book.isbn, 
    titulo_ori: this.book.titulo_ori, 
    sinop: this.book.sinop, 
    n_pag: this.book.n_pag, 
    _token: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
};
```

You should only add the token to the headers if you had not done it before with something like

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
};
```

But if you are using Laravel default [frontend scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend) that's probably already done. If don't, use the previus code.

But remember, in both  cases you will need that meta tag in your page `<head>`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

---

Not related, but for all the routes you write after `Auth::routes()`, you don't need to manually add the auth middleware `->middleware('auth')`

```
Auth::routes();
Route::resource('/books', 'books\BooksController');
```

Comment: thank you for the very complete answer, i fixed the problem